# How to import less modules with JSX in Vue2?

Tags: webpack, less, vuejs2

I'm using Vue2 with JSX template, I want to load the less as modules in the components, but there got a little errors, such as

`import styles from './ListItem.less'
export default {
  functional: true,
  render (h, context) {
    return (
      <div class={styles.listItem}>
      </div>
    )
  }
}`

the errors:

`This relative module was not found:
* ./ListItem.less in ./src/pages/treatment/ListItem.js`

my webpack loaders

```
 {
    test: /\.less$/,
    loader: 'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=2&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
    include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
  },
```

The 'ListItem.less' file and the component in the same folder!
How to config can be make it to be worked?